# How to consitently roundtrip with std::put_time std::get_time when the time string uses a "PM" field?

Tags: c++

EDIT: initialized tmb.tm_isdst to 0

I'm having problems parsing dates with an "AM"/"PM" field. Generally it seems to ignore this field regardless of the conversion specifier combos I use. Sometimes it seems to parse the time randomly.

The example date I'm parsing is

```
08/22/2020 10:16:57 PM
```

I'm using the `"en_US.utf-8"` locale and the following conversion specifier strings:

```cpp
"%x %I:%M:%S %p" //ignores AM/PM
"%x %X" // hour gets a random number and minutes/seconds equal 0
"%x %r" // hour gets a random number and minutes/seconds equal 0
```

I've tried x86-64 GCC 5 to 10 and x86-64 clang 3.4.1 to 10.

Here's the sample code that fails to do a roundtrip ([live code w/ godbot](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEJM6kt6ADJ5amAHLGARpmJcA7KQAOqBYXVaPUMTMwtffzU6W3snI1d3Ti8lFSjaBgJmYgJg41NzRWVMVUCMrIIYxxc3T0VM7NzQgoV6irsq%2BJqkgEpFVANiZA4AcikAZjtkQywAanExnXUW4kxmI3nscQAGAEFxyenMOYWFZdX1sc3d/dopg1n5nVZUFnYN7b3JCdvD48XUIwiPDed67Oa7OwEGaAuwQbriDyyMEzFEtdAgEBqIyYAD6UKh8wAIjNOABWACcAA5OGNuAA2JLzJE7FGogjozFGGYELlEmYAKjRGOeryxmAgUjpBHhY2ZrJmQpAyzswDOawVCiZH3lpwAdHh4gZxYqRWxxVJJFocQBVBi6gwEKgAWkpFu6MrlrNOf0eCvZGO8DrxBvNkilRlIc0kkikpIAHlHSQBJECxgCyqckpIYiZB0Y9H21Xv9KH6BIWvr1yzhPoWfo5VlYWuuyLZHJ53PizZZXoUx02l3rGOAmAIwexErDPOcpAtsYTsZT6cz2dzbu78unup5OLwCnQLWOxK2G%2BLHLQDtrOijkgAnqtiH3/LcjpxyVstqnSToCBar53nG3IwcXvLJ/0VRtTzbDEL3LHRfQtIw6AIJBxG/X90LQn8/0eX0tx3JDaHAktINlItoNLS9cLrC10GYW8v2wzDMOjf98OAow6NvYiG20JsyNbIdKLghDowQfp3CwjCmOw1jqOvdicXEgYeIxUjPQo2D/0QuwFEY6SDJwis60Uow7FUkB1PIoStPkm8lGQPSpOcljJDY%2BIgJxByLKswTFVs4zr1olp9Jc2S3LsxS9wPES6wgvioJssttOjMUWjWbxQtc/8ICMABrMVJ3DZx3W7BFCWGXpWBAYZSWGUhTGGLZ6tQGr4JkOQFQkoYozGTh6oIGrmvdUg8pAUk6V1MYxkkbhuC2cluCzThJEpOkhBq7h6sa5rSFa4Z6r0rZSEGprKtIOBYCQNAjG8PB2DICgIBuu6HpAYBSU4Y6qHugg3D0iBnCG%2BrnDsLIGOGfrSBu7F6AAeVoVgId2rBAVEdhgdIfAVhKAA3TA9LOyw42KB0Rl2yFlEx1g8GcYhwb0LAaqhghiANZnzpoegmDNLheAECxhFEFA5DkIRab0yBelQbw0kJp0nTRIkJA6mROChlJijSTRtEaUwLCsSo4gSQQIgCOg9dNvxzdoI3qkSQpUlKVpLYsTWSjoMpsjtzoHfShp9DyQR/baWJ7a4XoFG6jhOCqmq6oazH9rjNanTpbgZmAZBkBmUldU4GYIFwQgSF6iwZj0W77rcMvugr0WZAG4GRrG6NdS%2BLYPFJDxpspMZu62SkvGq4YtsTon9sOkBjtO4aLpgRAQDLQMCHISgXurh3MHwIgHa5xhXhj3gAHd6cyyHzpHhOdpamrxgL4/CAQGYU7pNOM6znO85Z5velbzhdTcDGHSSkWwkhvhpB%2BUkkgNqj22knGqU8Z6/1gZIeBE9EEnRQfjR8gQQDcCAA%3D%3D)):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <locale>
#include <iomanip>
 
int main(){
    std::time_t t = 1598134617;
    std::tm tm = *std::localtime(&t);
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss.imbue(std::locale("en_US.utf-8"));
    ss << std::put_time(&tm, "%x %I:%M:%S %p");

    std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;

    std::tm tmb;
    ss >> std::get_time(&tmb,"%x %I:%M:%S %p");
    tmb.tm_isdst = 0;
    std::cout << "years since 1900:\t" << tmb.tm_year << std::endl;
    std::cout << "month:\t\t\t" << tmb.tm_mon << std::endl;
    std::cout << "day:\t\t\t" << tmb.tm_mday << std::endl;
    std::cout << "hour:\t\t\t" << tmb.tm_hour << std::endl;
    std::cout << "mins:\t\t\t" << tmb.tm_min << std::endl;
    std::cout << "secs:\t\t\t" << tmb.tm_sec << std::endl;
    std::cout << "dst:\t\t\t" << tmb.tm_isdst << std::endl;
    std::cout << "timestamp:\t\t" << (mktime(&tmb));
}
```

This code outputs the wrong timestamp thus failing the roundtrip because of the "PM" field not being parsed.

The timestamp should be 1598134617; prints 1598091417:

```
08/22/2020 10:16:57 PM
years since 1900:   120
month:              7
day:                22
hour:               10
mins:               16
secs:               57
dst:                0
timestamp:          1598091417
```

Any idea on how to parse an "AM"/"PM" field consistently in c++?

Comment: When using clang, add this to your command line: `-stdlib=libc++`

Comment: Thanks Howard! This fixes parsing on all 3 time conversion specifier strings I was trying (`"%x %I:%M:%S %p"` , `"%x %X"`, and `"%x %r"`).

I accept this comment as the best answer. Please do post as an answer so that I can mark it, and make it useful to other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using clang, add this to your command line: `-stdlib=libc++`.  This uses the llvm implementation of the `std::get_time` and `std::put_time` functions.

Answer (score 0):

You have committed the cardinal (and popular!) sin of not initializing the `tm_isdst` member of your `std::tm tmb`.  I don't know what its value is in your example, but when I tested your code it gave me some seemingly random offset from the expected value even when the time was in the AM.  Adding `tmb.tm_isdst = -1;` after the declaration of `tmb` fixes the problem.  This is because `mktime()` depends on this value, but `std::get_time()` (and `strptime()`) does not set it.

Setting `tm_isdst = -1` means "I want the system to decide whether DST was in effect or not at the provided time."  This automatic mode works perfectly so long as the time is not ambiguous (e.g. during a "fall back" daylight saving time transition).

Petition your local lawmakers to abandon DST, and your compiler writers to warn about use of partially-initialized `struct tm`.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion about that uninitialized member, but I still get the exact same values. How did you compile yours to get it to work? I updated my answer with your suggestion (I tried initializing it with 0, -1, and 1). Btw, luckily, my local lawmakers have not adopted DST

Comment: Well I am using Clang, don't have GCC.  I'll leave this answer because it is critical for your code to work in DST-afflicted regions, even if it's not sufficient to fix the problem on your machine (which I have to think may be related to your locale somehow).

Comment: I tried clang but that didn't help either. I'm imbuing the stream's locale with std::locale("en_US.utf-8"). I'll try some others... that could be it.

Comment: What happens if you don't imbue?

Comment: If I don't imbue the roundtrip is worse. The year gets formatted to a 2 digit string. But when parsing it expects a 4 digit string so that tm_year ends up equal to 20. The unixtime becomes a negative int representing a date in 1920 (-1557668583).

The time still ignores the PM part.

Comment: @Cesar, you do realize that the tm_year is supposed to be a small number, since it is the actual year - 1900, right? "20" in "tm_year" is what will give you 1920, since you must add 1900 to it when you use it somehow.

Comment: By the way, I defined the following macros to help with the issue of setting and getting values from struct tm. They are:

#define TO_TM_YEAR(Y) Y - 1900
#define FROM_TM_YEAR(Y) Y + 1900
#define TO_TM_MON(M) M - 1
#define FROM_TM_MON(M) M + 1
#define TO_TM_MDAY(M) M
#define FROM_TM_MDAY(M) M
#define TO_TM_WDAY(W) W - 1
#define FROM_TM_WDAY(W) W + 1
#define TO_TM_YDAY(Y) Y - 1
#define FROM_TM_YDAY(Y) Y + 1

So, setting will be tm.tm_wday = TO_TM_WDAY(3), and getting a value will be auto wday = FROM_TM_WDAY(tm.tm_wday), etc.